# Differential equation with right side derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differentialequation: 
$$\gamma'(x) = \alpha \gamma(x) \; \forall x \in (0,\infty)$$
and
$$D_+\gamma(x) = \alpha \gamma(x) \; \forall x \in [0, \infty)$$
with starting value $\gamma(0) = 1$.
I am searching for soultions on $[0,\infty)$. It is clear, that $\gamma(x) = e^{\alpha x}$ is a soultion of this differential equation but i wonder if it is the only one. [$D_+$ denotes the right side derivative]

Comment: If the right-side derivative supports a product rule, you can use the integrating factor $e^{-αx}$ to get (probably) $D_+(e^{-αx}γ(x))=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! It actually does. 
You might aswell post this as an answer.